# Inserting into WP DB

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, database

I had initially asked a question based on my code (which has since been removed), I need some help/guidance in creating a plugin.

Scenario: I have created a custom post type (CPT), now I need to insert values into the CPT from a database table external to the wp environment. This routine needs to run once every hour, no of rows can range from 50 - 500.

What is my best course of action?

Side question: Do I separate my CPT code from the insert routine code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **wp_cron** to run a job every hour. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron
Use **$wpdb->get_results** to fetch data from your external table.
Example:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM my_table";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($q, OBJECT);
foreach ( $results as $result) {
}
```

Insert new CPT-posts using **wp_insert_post()** http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post

Comment: thanks windyjonas, will give it a try and let you know how i go, so in terms of best practice (first plugin here), should i split the code of CPT and the insert code? or keep them all together.

Comment: i never heard back from windyjonas however i will accept his response as the answer. thanks again windyjonas for you help.